# Perspective transform multiple objects but without warping these objects, only their size and position, not their shape

Tags: adobe-photoshop, perspective

I'm looking to do one thing in Photoshop, but I'm not sure how to explain it.

Let's say I have multiple identical ball images, each one on a different layer, or as a separate smart object. They're all arranged randomly on the canvas, without overlapping.

I want to apply a perspective transform to them all, so that the balls that are closer in perspective become bigger, the ones that are further away become smaller. However, a regular perspective transform distorts the shape of each ball. I'm looking for something that keeps the round shape of each ball, and only changes the ball's size and position depending on the perspective. Can something like that be done in Photoshop? Or maybe some other software?

Comment: I think you'd need to render this in 3D.

Comment: That's what I eventually decided to do, it's more complicated but the effect will be much better